# How would I write regex for getting the variable type from a variable comment?

Tags: php, regex, docblocks

I'm looking for a regex string to parse a property type from it's comment as below.

```
/**
 * Identity
 * 
 * @var integer
 */
protected $id;
```

I'm using the ReflectionProperty class to get the comment as a string as the var dump below:

```
string(55) "/** * Identity * * @var integer */"
```

How would use the regex to return the type after @var and nothing else.

Thanks

Comment: use `preg_replace('~.*@var(.*).*\*/(.*)?~is', '$1', $text);` or `preg_match_all('/@var(.*)[^*\/]/i', $text, $matches);`

Comment: You should put this as an answer so I can mark it as answered (with your answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposed solution in the comments seems rather excessive... should be much easier like this - as types never contain spaces, just match until the space.

```
/@var\s*([^\s]+)/i
```

https://regex101.com/r/xM6kL3/2